# What's the proof for this formula for non-separable differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The formula $$y = e^{-H(x)}[\int{e^{-H(x)}*q(x)dx}+c]$$ is the one in question, where $H(x) = \int{p(x)}dx$, for equations of the form $$y' + p(x)y = q(x)$$

This is the equation given by my teacher, but he didn't present a proof. What's the name of this formula and what is its proof?

(I have no idea if the formula I just presented is the one you normally see in the field, just the one I saw in class)

Comment: This is the integrating factor method of solving first order linear differential equations.. you should be able to find more information for this all over the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is frequently referred to as the "integrating factor" and is actually a rather straightforward result!  The technique is based on trying to rewrite the left-hand side of the equation as the derivative of the product of two functions.  First, we define

$$ H(x) = \int_0^x p(t) dt. $$

Notice that by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$$ H^\prime(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x p(t) dt = p(x). $$

Multiplying the given differential equation by $e^{H(x)}$ we obtain

$$ y^\prime e^{H(x)} + e^{H(x)} p(x) y = e^{H(x)} q(x)$$

Next, notice that by the Chain Rule we have that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} e^{H(x)} = H^\prime(x) e^{H(x)} = p(x)e^{H(x)},$$

And now for the real trickery of the method.  We notice that the left-hand side can be rewritten using the product rule (check this!),

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[ y e^{H(x)} \right] = y^\prime e^{H(x)} + e^{H(x)} p(x) y = e^{H(x)} q(x). $$

Now, we integrate both sides (again using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to "cancel out" the derivative on the left-hand side)

$$ y e^{H(x)} = \int_0^x e^{H(t)} q(t) dt + c. $$

From here it is easy to arrive at the result,

$$ y(x) = e^{-H(x)} \left( \int_0^x e^{H(t)} q(t) dt + c \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

$H(x)$ is the so-called integrating factor for the DE. Just multiply both sides of teh equation by $e^{H(x)}$ to get $e^{H(x)}y'+e^{H(x)}p(x)y=e^{H(x)}q(x)$. You can now recognize the left side as the derivative of $e^{H(x)}y$. Integrating this equation gives $e^{H(x)}y=\int e^{H(x)}q(x)+c$. Multiply both sides by $e^{-H(x)}$ and you get the answer.